# Custom OpenAM authentication Module showing "An internal authentication error has occurred"

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, openam

I am having issues developing a custom authentication module for Forgerock's OpenAM even after following the step by step guide. Looking at the Authentication log file located in ..\openam\debug folder, I can find the following error.

---

```
pageTimeOut : 60
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:143 PM BST: Thread[http-8080-4,5,main]
Thread[http-8080-4,5,main]Waiting..2
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:143 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Error during login.. 
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:144 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2999)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2789)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:731)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.AMLoginContext.runLogin(AMLoginContext.java:554)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.JAASLoginThread.run(JAASLoginThread.java:55)

amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:146 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Error retrieving SSOToken :
com.iplanet.sso.SSOException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:176)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:192)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:307)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.getSSOToken(LoginState.java:1926)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.logFailed(LoginState.java:4892)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.logFailed(LoginState.java:4840)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.AMLoginContext.runLogin(AMLoginContext.java:757)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.JAASLoginThread.run(JAASLoginThread.java:55)
Caused by: com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.refresh(Session.java:1523)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1159)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1106)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:168)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.service.SessionService.checkSession(SessionService.java:1271)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.service.SessionService.getSessionInfo(SessionService.java:1230)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.doRefresh(Session.java:1536)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.access$400(Session.java:113)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session$3.run(Session.java:1512)
    at com.sun.identity.session.util.RestrictedTokenContext.doUsing(RestrictedTokenContext.java:86)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.refresh(Session.java:1509)
    ... 10 more

amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:146 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Error while retrieving SSOToken for login failure: Authentication Error!!|auth_error_template.jsp
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Came to before if Failed loop
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
retrieving configuration: MODULE=Sample;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
cached configs {MODULE=Application;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML=[Ljavax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;@1176e8a, MODULE=Sample;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML=[Ljavax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;@14965e5, MODULE=DataStore;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML=[Ljavax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;@14e7b87, MODULE=LDAP;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML=[Ljavax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;@7ad957}
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
indexType = 5
indexName=Sample
orgDN=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
clientType=genericHTML
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
getAppConfigurationEntry[], found MODULE=Sample;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
indexType = 5
indexName=Sample
orgDN=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
clientType=genericHTML
amAuthConfig:05/31/2015 07:51:25:147 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
AMConfiguration.cloneConfigurationEntry, orgDN=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org, entries=[Ljavax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;@14965e5
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
configName is : MODULE=Sample;ORGANIZATION=dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org;CLIENT=genericHTML
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
ModuleSet is : [Sample]
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
ModuleSet is : [Sample]
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
ModuleList is : Sample
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
moduleList is :Sample
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:148 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
failureModulelist :Sample
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:149 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Error retrieving SSOToken :
com.iplanet.sso.SSOException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:176)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:192)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:307)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.getSSOToken(LoginState.java:1926)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.logFailed(LoginState.java:4892)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.LoginState.logFailed(LoginState.java:4849)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.AMLoginContext.runLogin(AMLoginContext.java:786)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.service.JAASLoginThread.run(JAASLoginThread.java:55)
Caused by: com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.refresh(Session.java:1523)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1159)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1106)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:168)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Session state is invalid. AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw84FhQX_yIazyd7D8s43vJbTGqVnUdjSI.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNzk2NTA2MjUyODMwMjgzMTI1Mw..*
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.service.SessionService.checkSession(SessionService.java:1271)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.service.SessionService.getSessionInfo(SessionService.java:1230)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.doRefresh(Session.java:1536)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.access$400(Session.java:113)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session$3.run(Session.java:1512)
    at com.sun.identity.session.util.RestrictedTokenContext.doUsing(RestrictedTokenContext.java:86)
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.refresh(Session.java:1509)
    ... 10 more

amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:149 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
Error while retrieving SSOToken for login failure: Authentication Error!!|auth_error_template.jsp
amAuth:05/31/2015 07:51:25:150 PM BST: Thread[Thread-72,5,main]
resProperty is.. :Authentication Error!!|auth_error_template.jsp
```

---

Am I missing anything here because I've followed the step by step tutorial available on Forgerock or is there any other things I am meant to do which have not been listed in the tutorial?

Comment: Did you add your custom class to OpenAM web app?

Comment: @Bernhard
Yes I did. The custom authentication module jar was dropped inside the correct folder

Comment: the stacktrace suggests that the classloader could not find the configured class, so either there seems to be an OpenAM configuration (class name for the auth module) or a packetizing issue

Comment: @Bernhard
You are right. I placed the jars in the correct location and everything worked fine. Thanks

Comment: OpenAM is a shit product. No help available. Behaves erratic. Better shift to a better one.